# How to call a Post api with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

How can i call a Post method with multiple parameters using HttpClient?

I am using the following code with a single parameter:

```
var paymentServicePostClient = new HttpClient();
paymentServicePostClient.BaseAddress = 
                  new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaymentServiceUri"]);

PaymentReceipt payData = SetPostParameter(card);
var paymentServiceResponse = 
   paymentServicePostClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/billpayment/", payData).Result;
```

I need to add another parameter userid. How can i send the parameter along with the 'postData'?

WebApi POST method prototype:

```
public int Post(PaymentReceipt paymentReceipt,string userid)
```

Comment: How action from your Web API?

Comment: 'action from webapi' means?

Comment: The method you want your POST request call in Web Api

Comment: @Cuong Le , I'd updated the post

Comment: With this Web Api, I don't see userId?

Comment: I need to add it and call the api from the code behind. Dont know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`UserId` should be in query string:

```
var paymentServiceResponse = paymentServicePostClient
                            .PostAsJsonAsync("api/billpayment?userId=" + userId.ToString(), payData)
                            .Result;
```

Comment: This is just what I needed to get over my hump.  However, I find it interesting that, at least if the first parameter is not a complex type, the Web API will not convey it to the calling function unless it is also included in the query string.  Now I have to leave it in both places, because if I take it out of the function arguments, C# will not compile.  PostAsJsonAsync has to have that second parameter no matter what.  But when stepping through the code, I can't see that it actually uses the parameter unless it is also in the query string.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use a view model on your Web Api controller that contains both properties. So instead of:

```
public HttpresponseMessage Post(PaymentReceipt model, int userid)
{
    ...
}
```

use:

```
public HttpresponseMessage Post(PaymentReceiptViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

where the `PaymentReceiptViewModel` will obviously contain the `userid` property. Then you will be able to call the method normally:

```
var model = new PaymentReceiptViewModel()
model.PayData = ...
model.UserId = ...
var paymentServiceResponse = paymentServicePostClient
    .PostAsJsonAsync("api/billpayment/", model)
    .Result;
```

Comment: is it to be like that? A post cannot have one more parameter?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imo, the currently accepted one only works for simple types

Comment: @reggaeguitar.  I disagree.  For one, this doesn't directly answer the question.  But also, from a Test Automation Engineer's perspective who is building up integration tests for a legacy system, sometimes the format of the controller is out of your hands.  So I think the question asked is perfectly legitimate in its own right.  In my own case, simple types are all that is being passed into some of these functions, so the currently accepted answer is just what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

In my case my existing ViewModels don't line up very nicely with the data I want to post to my WebAPI. So, instead of creating an entire new set of model classes, I posted an anonymous type, and had my Controller accept a dynamic.

```
var paymentServiceResponse = paymentServicePostClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/billpayment/", new { payData, userid }).Result;



public int Post([FromBody]dynamic model)
{
    PaymentReceipt paymentReceipt = (PaymentReceipt)model.paymentReceipt;
    string userid = (string)model.userid;

    ...

}
```

(I'd be curious to hear some feedback on this approach. It's definitely a lot less code.)

Comment: Awesome solution. Using `[FromBody]` and `[FromUri]` is so nice and easy.